# getAllByRole - TestingLibraryElementError: Unable to find an accessible element with the role "option"

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, testing, jestjs

I am trying to learn how to unit test, and my first test is trying to test a selector dropdown menu. I am using react jest to test.

When I try to access the options in the selector I get this error: TestingLibraryElementError: Unable to find an accessible element with the role "option"

[Error in terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cpx85.png)

My selector looks like this

```
export function Selector({ data, name, defaultVal, labelStyle, ...rest }) {

    return (
        <>
            <label htmlFor={name} style={labelStyle}>{name}</label>
            <Select id={name} defaultValue={defaultVal} {...rest} >
                {data && data.map(n => <Option role="option" key={n} value={n}>{n}</Option>)}
            </Select>
        </>
    )
}
```

My test file looks like this:

```
import Selectors, { Selector } from "./Selectors";
import renderer from "react-test-renderer";
import store from "../../redux/store";
import {
  render,
  cleanup,
  fireEvent,
  getAllByRole,
  screen
} from "@testing-library/react";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import "@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect";

afterEach(cleanup);

const options = [
  {
      key: 'All Namespaces',
      value: 'All Namespaces',
  },
  {
      key: 'Production',
      value: 'Production',
  },
  {
      key: 'Default',
      value: 'Default',
  },
];

const MySelector = () => (
  <Selector
      data-testid="selector"
      data={options}
      defaultVal={options[0].value}
  />
);

it("can change the value of the Selector dropdown", () => {
  const { getByTestId } = render(<MySelector />);
  const selector = getByTestId('selector');
  const display = selector.children[0];

  expect(screen.getAllByRole('option').length).toBe(options.length);

  expect(display.textContent).toBe(options[0].text);

  console.log(display.textContent);

  fireEvent.click(selector);

  expect(screen.getAllByRole('option').length).toBe(3)

  const selectorOptions = getAllByRole(selector, 'option');

  fireEvent.click(selectorOptions[2]);

  expect(display.textContent).toBe(options[2].text);

  console.log(display.textContent);
});
```

Hopefully someone can help me with this, thank you!

Comment: Does your `Option` component actually render the role attribute in the html  ?

Comment: I thought it did by doing this? But I might bewrong, have never tried before
<Option role="option" key={n} value={n}>{n}</Option>

Comment: Where is `Option` component from ? Which library ?

Comment: The Option component is the Select component from ant design. https://ant.design/components/select/

import { Select} from 'antd'
const { Option } = Select;

Comment: From looking at the source code of the Option component, it looks like they do some optimizations and one of them is only adding the `role="option"` property to 3 items only. The currently hovered one, the previous and the next one. And they only add them in the DOM after you first open the select.

Comment: I see, thank you! I didn't even realize that they could remove it. Then I'll find some other way to test. Thanks again

Comment: Please do not add "Solved" into the title. The system will still see this question as unanswered. If you've found an answer to your question, use the answer field below so the system knows this question has been answered.

Answer (score 0):

It was not possible to add the role tag to the third party component since the source code has removed it for optimalization.